# Stuck on building a customer support chatbot from scratch using reddit dataset

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network

I've trained a model who can mimic day to day conversations occurring on reddit. But my problem is that I want it to reply to a specific use case based on the vocabulary it has learned.

Summary: I am building a chatbot and there are many use cases. I've trained a model with a reddit dataset and now I have a model who can mimic reddit conversation. I want it to map it's vocabulary to one of my use cases. How should I tackle this scenario?

Any idea? Please help, I've tried searching the internet for days, but no answer.

Comment: From Liam Roels: I think you should be more specific. 
What are you using right now? How have you trained your bot? ...

We can't help you if you are not clear about your methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Specifically, I am using numpy. And, yes I've trained my bot on reddit comment dataset. The missing puzzle peice that I want is that how can I map my use cases with my trained model.